# SQL script for join with self and change value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this

[image]

What should I do to get output like this

[image]

I try with this but, I cant get the others value

```
SELECT A.UserName AS UserName, B.UserName AS Parent
FROM test A, test B
WHERE A.UserName <> B.UserName
AND (B.ID = A.Parent)
```

Results

[image]

Comment: To get `NULL` you need to use `OUTER SELF JOIN` (for example, `LEFT`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always use `explicit join`, and you need to use `left join`:

```
select t1.id,
       t1.UserName , 
       t2.UserName ParentUsername
from tablename t1
left join tablename t2
    ON t1.parent = t2.ID
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `left outer join`
this query works fine

```
SELECT A.UserName AS UserName, B.UserName AS Parent
FROM test A left outer join test B on (B.ID = A.Parent);
```

it worked for me with MySQL db.

Answer (score -1):

Try a join statement:

```
SELECT A.UserName UserName, 
       B.UserName Parent
  FROM test A
  JOIN test B
    ON A.parent = B.ID
```